# Get values from url with PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to get values from a url using php. With basename I only get the last part but i need the part before that as well.

This is the domain: `http://mydomain.nl/first/second/third/`

```
$url = parse_url($entry['source_url']);
$urlFragments = explode('/', $url);
$second = $urlFragments[0];
$third = $urlFragments[1];
```

I need to use part second and part third.

Comment: Get path value and use explode() https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php function

Comment: `parse_url` returns an array (at least when used this way) - and feeding an array to explode makes no sense.

Answer (score 6):

**@idka-80** try this,

```
$url_components = parse_url($url);
echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_filter(explode("/",$url_components['path'])));
```

Answer (score 0):

This script can help you
First of all, to make it simple I remove `http://` part and then explode it with `/` and get a different part of the data which is separated by `/`

```php
<?php

$url = "http://mydomain.nl/first/second/third/";
$url = str_replace("http://", "", $url);
$urlFragments = explode('/', $url);

$yourDomain = $urlFragments[0];
$first = $urlFragments[1];
$second = $urlFragments[2];
$third = $urlFragments[3];

echo $first . ", " . $second . ", " . $third;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can tell from the fatal error, you're making a wrong assumption about how [parse_url()](https://php.net/parse_url) works:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: explode(): Argument #2 ($string) must be of type string, array given

If you only want a specific fragment, you need to tell which one:

```
$url = parse_url($entry['source_url'], PHP_URL_PATH);
// ^ Also give it a better name, such as `$path`
```

You also possibly want to discard leading and trailing slashes:

```
$urlFragments = explode('/', trim($url, '/'));
```